# Linux systemd service file to start and stop a minecraft server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am trying to run a minecraft server on a remote linux instance.

I would like the instance to start up the server on a screen named `serverscreen` which is owned by the user named `minecraft` once the system boots up, and run a stop command to the `serverscreen` when the instance shuts down. Then, it needs to wait untill the server has stopped before actually shutting down.

I am quite new to linux but I have managed to come up with a few commands that work, but I have issues trying to start and stop the server automatically.

I have tried quite a few things, like creating a .sh script to run on startup with `crontab -e @reboot script.sh`, or create a file in `etc/rc.local` with `#!/bin/sh sh script.sh`, but those methods didn't seem to work properly for me. Also, they do not run un shutdown unfortunately. Therefore, I thought it would be best to create a service file named `minecraft.service` with the following commands:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Nice=5
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
InaccessibleDirectories=/root /sys /srv /media -/lost+found
NoNewPrivileges=true
WorkingDirectory=/opt/minecraft/server
ReadWriteDirectories=/opt/minecraft/server

#### Command to start the server.
ExecStart=sudo -u minecraft screen -dmS serverscreen java -Xms6G -Xmx6G -jar /opt/minecraft/server/forgeserver.jar nogui

#### Command to stop the server.
ExecStop=sudo -u minecraft screen -S serverscreen -p 0 -X eval "stuff stop^M"
##### Try to wait untill the server has stopped. I am not sure about this line of code since I haven't been able to test it properly.
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "while ps -p $MAINPID > /dev/null; do /bin/sleep 1; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but when running this, it gives me an error saying that I did not provide an absolute path for something.

Could someone help me setup a service file that will boot up the server on a screen named `serverscreen` for the user `minecraft`, and run command `stop` when the instance shuts down after the server has been stopped?

Comment: "it gives me an error saying that I did not provide an absolute path for something". what is that 'something'?

Comment: @Riz Thats what I am wondering to. it gives the following error:  Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: sudo -u minecraft /usr/bin/screen -dmS serverscreen usr/bin/java -Xms6G -Xmx6G -jar /opt/minecraft/server/forgeserver.jar nogui

Comment: My suggestion would be to put each command inside a bash script and do ExecStop=/bin/bash $yourscript

Comment: Thank you! using a bash script in order to run the commands works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Riz, the service now works as intended by using a bash script in order to run the commands.

Comment: Really bad form to answer your own question with an empty answer. 

What was the resulting systemd file for ExecStop?
What did the bash script look like?